# JSF Custom Validator: h:message is not being rendered

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following FacesValidator:

```
@RequestScoped
@FacesValidator("passwordValidator")
public class PasswordValidator implements Validator {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "TradeCenterPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    public void validate(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent comp, final Object values) throws ValidatorException {
        String password = (String)values;
        System.out.println("passwordValidator():" + password);
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("user.findByUsername");
        q.setParameter("username", context.getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
        User user = (User)q.getSingleResult();
        String pwhash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(password + user.getSalt());
        System.out.println("User: " + user.getUsername() + ", PwHash: " + pwhash + ", Password: " + user.getPassword());

        if (!pwhash.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            System.out.println(comp.getClientId(context) + ": Old password is wrong!");
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "The old password was not entered correctly.",
                    ""
            );
            context.addMessage(comp.getClientId(context), msg);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Wich gets used in the following way:

```
<h:form id="profileform" action="#{userController.updatePassword}">
    <h:messages errorClass="error_message" globalOnly="true"/>
    ...
    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Old password:" />
    <h:inputSecret id="password" name="password" label="Old password">
        <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="15" />
        <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator"/>
    </h:inputSecret>
    <h:message for="password" errorClass="error_message"/>
    ...
</h:form>
```

The problem now is, that the message which the Validator generates is never displayed. I know it gets generated, because in the Glassfish-Log I can see

```
profileform:password: Old password is wrong!
```

I can't see any error in this especially since the message for the `f:validateLength` gets displayed if the password is to long or to short.
If I do

```
context.addMessage(null, msg);
```

instead of

```
context.addMessage(comp.getClientId(context), msg);
```

the Message is shown in the `h:messages` component.
Has anyone an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just wondering, are you using Seam 3? Since normally PhaseListeners are not injection targets and injecting the entity manager factory would not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see nothing, because you've constructed the `FacesMessage` with a summary **and** a detail. When the detail is not `null`, then it will be displayed instead. Since you've set it with an empty string, you "see" an empty message. You basically need to set detail to `null` to get the summary to display.

But this isn't exactly the way you're supposed to set a message on a validation error. You should **just** throw the `ValidatorException` and JSF will add the in the `ValidatorException` constructed message to the context itself based on the component's client ID.

So, you need to replace

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
        "The old password was not entered correctly.",
        ""
);
context.addMessage(comp.getClientId(context), msg);
throw new ValidatorException(msg);
```

by

```
String msg = "The old password was not entered correctly.";
throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(msg));
```

and it will work as you expect.